# System verilog - streaming operator multidimensional array to stream of bits

Tags: system-verilog

I cant figure out how to take multidimensional array such as:

```
 bit unsigned [10:0] img  [3:0][3:0];
```

And make this array as a stream of bits.
Think of it as an 4X4 image that each pixel is 11 bits in my memory that I want to read, and I have 1 input pin that get my image as a stream of bits, I prefer if you have any idea how to do that, to get the data in streams of 11 bits (lets say I have a typedef).
I want to declare an array like this in the testbench, and send this array as a stream of bits to my module that I want to test.

I tried to do any variation i saw online, but nothing useful:

```
 stream   = { >> {img}};
```

or

```
 stream   = { << {img}};
```

defined stream as bits or int , exc.

edit:
the errors I got from the above attempts were identical:

```
 "near text ">>"; expecting an operand"
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

edit:I'm working with quartus2 and with modelsim-sltera simulator.

edit: Full example, this is my testbench (at first I just tried to make the streaming operator work):

```
module streamtest(); 
logic clk;
bit unsigned [10:0] img   [3:0][3:0]= '{'{11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000},'{11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000},'{11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000},'{11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000}};
bit unsigned [10:0]   kernel[2:0][2:0] = '{'{11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000},'{11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000},'{11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000,11'b10001000000}};
bit [31:0]  stream   = { >> {img}}; 
initial begin
    clk = 1'b0;
     //     stream   = { >> {img}};//tried inside and outside of initial block

end
StreamConv(.pixelin(stream));
endmodule
```

StreamConv is the module I want to send the array as stream of bits, he is empty now so I didn't posted him.

one more thing when I use the above tb I get the error:"Error(10170):near text: ">>";  expecting an operand." this is after clicking on Analysis&Synthesis operation.

Comment: Both look OK to me. What simulator are you using?

Comment: thanks for your respond, Ill update my question this is  necessary for my question.

Comment: Cross-posting is frowned upon: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/360217/system-verilog-streaming-operator-multidimensional-array-to-stream-of-bits

Comment: Modelsim definitely supports the streaming operator. But some syntax errors are caused by the code before it. Can you show us a minimal complete example?

Comment: "Cross-posting is frowned upon: "-> and what wrong with me posting in two different and unrelated forums?

Dave Ill update my post with a complete example. thanks.

Comment: They not different when you use the same *system-verilog* tags on both forums,

Answer (score 1):

This is a synthesis tool/version support issue. The code you wrote is legal SystemVerilog syntax, except the target `stream` needs to have at least 16*111=176 bits.

Answer (score 0):

first thanks a lot dave_59, Ive already tried much bigger size for stream didn't help.

But I did find the answer, I use quartus 2 and the tool doesn't support streaming operators , as can be seen in Section 11—"Operators and Expressions", in the link below:
http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.1/mergedProjects/hdl/vlog/vlog_list_sys_vlog.htm

Thanks a lot for your help, I hope this we help someone one day.